Сервер node js для отправки email - ошибка при отправке сообщений: invalid login:535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted
Я создал сайт на html и js. В нём имеется поле для ввода email и кнопка для отправки. Ещё я создал сервер node.js, к-рый должен отправить сообщение на выбранный адрес. Но когда я ввожу свой email в браузере и жму на кнопку, вижу сообщение "ошибка при отправке сообщений: invalid login:535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted." Как быть?



const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'мой_email@gmail.com',
    pass: 'мой_пароль'
  }
});

app.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'мой_email@gmail.com',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Привет от моего сайта',
    text: 'Привет, это мой сайт'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send('Ошибка при отправке сообщения: ' + error.message);
    } else {
      res.send('Сообщение успешно отправлено');
    }
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Сервер запущен на порту 3000');
});





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Пример формы</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="contact-form">
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Введите ваш email" required>
    <button type="submit" id="sm">Отправить</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      fetch('/send-email', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: email })
      })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => alert(data))
      .catch((error) => console.error('Ошибка:', error));
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>



Сейчас нельзя отправлять письма сторонними приложениями с аккаунтов mail.ru, yandex, gmail и т.д., используя основной пароль аккаунта.
Надо создавать отдельные пароли для приложений. Инструкция для GMail:
Нужно включить двухфакторную аутентификацию в аккаунте, с которого вы собираетесь отправлять письма.
После этого, в Chrome нажимаем на “Manage your Accounts” →Безопасность. Ищем блок “Вход в аккаунт” и нажимаем на “Пароли приложений”.
Теперь этот пароль можно использовать для отправки почты с помощью скрипта на вашем любимом языке программирования.
